# Android Preferences Initialization

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a problem with the initialization of Android preferences.
In `PreferenceStore.initalize()`, I have these 2 statements:
`mLogoOneCheck = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean(contextWrapper.getResources().getString(R.string.preferenceKeyLogoOne), true);`
`mLogoTwoCheck = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean(contextWrapper.getResources().getString(R.string.preferenceKeyLogoTwo), false);`
Note the boolean at the end of each statement with a default value for each. So the user long-clicks on the background, selects LiveWallpaper and then selects this livewallpaper (AE_LiveWallpaper_Test). The One icons slowly fall down the screen as expected. Now the user clicks `Settings -> Choose Logos` and sees a menu with One and Two. The problem is here: Both the checkboxes are checked. I would expect to see only the One box checked.

If I change the code so that both have a default value of true, then by some coincidence, there is no problem:
`mLogoOneCheck = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean(contextWrapper.getResources().getString(R.string.preferenceKeyLogoOne), true);`
`mLogoTwoCheck = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean(contextWrapper.getResources().getString(R.string.preferenceKeyLogoTwo) true);`

What am I doing wrong?

The entire project is on github:
https://github.com/falsedmitri/AE-LiveWallpaper_Test

To compile and run it you will need the following:
 https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEngine(GLES2-AnchorCenter)
 https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension(GLES2-AnchorCenter)

Comment: The boolean is a default.  Where are you actually setting the values in the SharedPreferences?

Comment: This occurs before setting values. The app is installed then started and the checkboxes are incorrect. The source code is available at the github link so you can see what is happening.